# How to get MySQL full version description with SQL statement (not console command)?

Tags: mysql, sql, version

In Microsoft SQL Server I get full version description with:

```
SELECT @@VERSION;
```

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64)   Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

And in Oracle Database with:

```
SELECT V.BANNER FROM (SELECT ROWNUM AS NFILA, BANNER FROM V$VERSION) V WHERE V.NFILA = 1
```

> Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Or PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT version();
```

> PostgreSQL 13.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5), 64-bit

But in MySQL with `SELECT @@version;` I get only the version number:

> 8.0.21

How to get the full version description with SQL statement (not console command) in MySQL? something like:

```
MySQL Community Edition 8.0.21 x64
```

O only the MySQL name product, something like:

```
MySQL Community Edition
```

Comment: There is at least 5 different [system variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_version) related to a version. You retrieve the value for only one of them.

Comment: @Akina Thanks I don't found that MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 1):

With @Akina's help this is the solution if someone not found information:

```
SELECT @@version_compile_machine;
SELECT @@version_compile_os;
SELECT @@version_comment;
```